# How to convert3D model to 2D blueprint

Tags: dictionary, image-processing, 3d, 2d

I want to convert 3D model to 2D blueprint using python or any algorithm.

I'm still looking for a way to make it happen

Comment: Please describe your 3D model.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use the `bmesh` module to extract the edges from a mesh.

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

def get_edges(obj):
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
    edges = [e for e in bm.edges]
    bm.free()
    return edges

edges = get_edges(bpy.context.object)
```

You can then use the `bgl` module to draw the edges on the screen.

```py
import bgl

def draw_edges(edges):
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glLineWidth(2)
    bgl.glBegin(bgl.GL_LINES)
    bgl.glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1)
    for e in edges:
        bgl.glVertex3f(*e.verts[0].co)
        bgl.glVertex3f(*e.verts[1].co)
    bgl.glEnd()
    bgl.glLineWidth(1)
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_BLEND)

draw_edges(edges)
```